# Binding Items in a Dialog

Tags: data-binding, dialog, fragment, sapui5

i'm trying to bind items in my fragment..

the table in my main view is like this...

```js
_loadContent: function(context) {
        let tbGenerations = this.getView().byId("tbGenerations");
        let template = tbGenerations.getBindingInfo("items").template;

        let path =
          "gia_es_odata>/CONTROLE_TELA_PARAM(P_MANDT='" +
          context.MANDT +
          "',P_ORGSTR='" +
          context.ORGSTR +
          "',P_PERIODO='" +
          context.PERIODO +
          "',P_ANO='" +
          context.ANO +
          "')/Results";

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          tbGenerations.bindItems(path, template);

          tbGenerations.getBinding("items").attachChange(() => {
            resolve();
          });
        });
```

I want to do almost the same thing on the dialog fragment.. how I do that? How do I start and why? I'm new in the development world, I'm learning fast, but there are hours that I get stuck and my co-worker who teaches me, took 3 days off .. haha
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the bind aggregation from api reference https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070